# How to login to the sandbox using salesforce Bulk API

Tags: python, salesforce, bulk

I'm trying to use python to connect to Salesforce Bulk API. However, I don't want to test my code on the real salesforce. I want to test with my sandbox. However, I don't know how to connect to sandbox only... I've tried to add sandbox=True but it doesn't work...

```
import salesforce_bulk

bulk=salesforce_bulk.SalesforceBulk(username="username",password="password")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but I had the same problem today, so maybe this will help someone.

This is a complete hack, but it works - probably a better hack would be to do this using salesforce-oauth-request (which does have a "sandbox=True" option), but I was logging in via beatbox anyway, so tried this first.

Gist is you log in to the sandbox using beatbox (which lets you specify your serverUrl) and then use that sessionId and instance_url to log in through salesforce_bulk.

```
import beatbox
from salesforce_bulk import SalesforceBulk

# log in to sandbox using beatbox
service = beatbox.PythonClient()

service.serverUrl = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/20.0'
user = 'user@user.com'
password = 'secret'
token = '12345'

service.login(user, password+token)

# the _Client_serverUrl has the instance url + some 
# SOAP stuff, so we need to strip that off
groups = service._Client__serverUrl.split('/')
instance_url = '/'.join(groups[:3])

# now we can use the instance_url and sessionId to 
# log into Salesforce through SalesforceBulk
bulk = sfdc_bulk_connect(instance_url, service.sessionId)
```

Answer (score 1):

The advice here may be a bit deprecated. I was able to get the bulk uploads working by combining the Salesforce and SalesforceBulk libraries. Note the domain that I am passing to the api as well the sand_box name that needs to be appended to the username.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from salesforce_bulk import SalesforceBulk
import json
from salesforce_bulk.util import IteratorBytesIO
from urllib.parse import urlparse

USER = "user@domain.com.<sandbox_name>"
PASS = "pass"
SEC_TOKEN = "token"
DOMAIN = "<domain>--<sandbox_name>.<instance>.my"

sf = Salesforce(username=USER, password=PASS, security_token=SEC_TOKEN, domain=DOMAIN)
bulk = SalesforceBulk(sessionId=sf.session_id, host=sf.sf_instance)
job = bulk.create_query_job("table", contentType='JSON')
batch = bulk.query(job, "select Id,LastName from table limit 5000")
bulk.close_job(job)
while not bulk.is_batch_done(batch):
    sleep(10)

for result in bulk.get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch):
    result = json.load(IteratorBytesIO(result))
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the package is install

This library will use the salesforce-oauth-request package (which you must install) to run the Salesforce OAUTH2 Web flow and return an access token.

And the  password did you have token or not ?